# Somar quantidade de variáveis repetidas PHP

Tags: php, magento

O trecho de código abaixo me retorna nomes e quantidades de produtos, sendo cada um em uma variável.

```
foreach ($orderItems as $order) {
    $order_data = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order['order_id']);
    $items = $order_data->getAllItems();
    $order_id = $order['order_id'];
    $total = $order_data->getGrandTotal();
    $customer_name = $order_data->getCustomerName();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product_id = $item->getProductId();
        if ($product_id == $id) {
             $tudo = $item->getName() .' - Quantidade: '. $item->getQtyOrdered().'<br/>';
        }
    }
        
    echo $tudo;
    }
```

#### Exemplo de saída:

Produto1 - Quantidade: 2

Produto1  - Quantidade: 7

Produto2 - Quantidade: 1

Produto2  - Quantidade: 1

#### Como eu poderia fazer para que a saída fosse a seguinte?

Produto1  - Quantidade: 9

Produto2 - Quantidade: 2

Comment: Indentei seu código para facilitar a leitura. O `echo $tudo` está dentro do `foreach $oderItems`? É que falta o fechamento `}`, deve ter sido na hora de fazer copy/paste aqui...

Comment: sim, o echo $tudo está dentro do foreach $oderItems.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de colocar o resultado em $tudo, a opção fácil seria usar num tabela "$tudo".
Aqui uma solução, bem básica.

```
    // Init quantidade
    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
           $product_id = $item->getProductId();
          $tudo[$product_id] = 0;     // Para cada Product, qt do inicio = 0
    }

    // Leitura das quantidades
     foreach ($items as $item) {
          $product_id = $item->getProductId();
           // Acumulação...
          $tudo[$product_id] = $tudo[$product_id] + $item->getQtyOrdered();
    }
```

Aqui, precisa ver quantos "tudo" vôcé tem, usando
        $num_tudo = sizeof($tudo);

e fazer um loop para ler o resultado.

Na primeira versão, o terceiro foreach foi errado.

Outra opção:

```
<?php

// Os dados que vamos contar
 $data = "truc,truc,machin,truc,machin,bidule,bidule,truc,truc";


$tab_data = explode(",",$data);
$nb_data = sizeof($tab_data);
 // 1- Preparar
for ($x=0; $x<$nb_data; $x++)
{
     $nome_prod = $tab_data[$x];
    $qt_data[$nome_prod] = 0;
}

 // Contar
 for ($x=0; $x<$nb_data; $x++)
 {
    $nome_prod = $tab_data[$x];
    $qt_data[$nome_prod]++;
 }


 // Aqui, temos mais de uma vez cada resultado

  // Vai dar para nos SOMENTE as keys de verdade
  $dest =  array_keys($qt_data);

 foreach ($dest as $key=>$value)
 {
     echo $value."=".$qt_data[$value]."<br>\n";
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: No primeiro `foreach` tinha que verficar se `$tudo[id]` já existe, não?

Comment: Olá Peter, obrigado pela ajuda! fiz como vc disse (ou ao menos como eu entendi) e o resultado foi a soma de todas as qt. resultou em 11

Answer (score 0):

Cara tive um problema parecido e resolvi ele da seguinte forma:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {

    if (isset($array[$i])) {
        $nome = $array[$i]["nome"]//o nome do produto
            //assim ele passa por todos os elementos
            for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($array); $j++) {

                    if (isset($array[$j])) {
                        $nome2 = $array[$j]["nome"];                            

                        if ($nome == $nome2){
                            $valor  = (int)$array[$i]["v"];//valor do produto
                            $valor2 = (int)$array[$j]["v"];//valor do segundo produto    

                            //se os nomes forem iguais soma os valores
                            $array[$i]["c"][1]["v"] = $valor + $valor2;    

                            //e exclui um dos produtos do array
                            unset($array[$j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Agora vc só tem q adaptar

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar um group by nos produtos dos pedidos,
seria algo parecido com isso:

```
$items = $order_data->getCollection()->getSelect()->group('product_id');
```

ou

```
$items = $order_data->getAllItems()->getSelect()->group('product_id');
```

Comment: em que lugar esse group by deveria ser inserido?

Comment: Substitua ($items = $order_data->getAllItems();) por um desses e testa para ver se da certo.